# List of all county (and equivalent) seats for the USA

Tags: usa, county

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all county seats for the USA? Specifically I'm looking for (if possible) the locality name, lat/long, county or equivalent name, and INCITS code.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoNames](http://geonames.org) contains this information, you would be looking for records with a feature code of `P.PPLA2` which is the seat of a second-order administrative division.